# Javascript - How to write json path when there's an integer tag

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

Javascript:

```
var json_obj = 
{
   "1111": {
       "name": Bob,
       "id": 1
   },
   "2222": {
       "name": Alice,
       "id": 2
   }
}
var first_name = json_obj.1111.name; // Gives me a missing ';' before statement error
```

In above code, json_obj is a part of a large json file used in our project.
I thought of changing json file to make it easy to locate elements but it is a large json file and is used throughout the project, can someone enlighten me as to how to locate elements in these situations?

Comment: `var first_name = json_obj['1111'].name;` use square bracket notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```js
var json_obj = {
  "1111": {
    "name": "Bob",
    "id": 1
  },
  "2222": {
    "name": "Alice",
    "id": 2
  }
}
var first_name = json_obj['1111'].name;

document.write(first_name);
```